# Scroll function executes also when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d6sdmtd/1/) as an answer to [How to build fullscreen slider like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364201/how-to-build-fullscreen-slider-like-this) (now on hold)
I know scrolling too fast bugs it and that scrolling both ways does the same thing, but my problem is that when the page loads, it automatically scrolls once 
Code I used is

```
var leftImg = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
var rightImg = document.getElementsByClassName('right');
var cur = 0;
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    leftImg[i].style.zIndex = rightImg[i].style.zIndex = -(i+1);
}

window.onmousewheel = changeImage();

function changeImage() {
  leftImg[cur].style.top= "-100%";
  rightImg[cur].style.top= "100%";
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.onmousewheel = changeImage; 
  leftImg[cur].style.zIndex=rightImg[cur].style.zIndex=-(cur+4);
  leftImg[cur].style.top=rightImg[cur].style.top="0";
  cur++;
  if(cur === 3) {
    cur = 0;
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    leftImg[i].style.zIndex = rightImg[i].style.zIndex = -(i+1);
}
  }
}, 3000);
  window.onmousewheel = preventDefault;
}
```

Why?

Comment: what is your requirement ?

Comment: just wanted to know why it scrolls once when the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED #2**

No need for the loop nor TimeOut

```
var cur = 2;
var zIndex = -1;

window.onmousewheel = changeImage;
function changeImage() {

    var leftImg = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
    var rightImg = document.getElementsByClassName('right');
    leftImg[cur].style.top = "-100%";
    rightImg[cur].style.top = "100%";
    if (leftImg[(cur + 1) % 3].style.top === "-100%") {
        leftImg[(cur + 1) % 3].style.zIndex = rightImg[(cur + 1) % 3].style.zIndex = (zIndex);
        leftImg[(cur + 1) % 3].style.top = rightImg[(cur + 1) % 3].style.top = "0%";

    }
    zIndex--;
    cur--;
    if (cur === -1) {
        cur = 2;
    }

}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d6sdmtd/6/)

Comment: Sorry, but still no

Comment: What browser are you using

Comment: I am using chrome. Apparently, onmousewheel isn't a cross browser event. 
I am trying to rewrite the function now

Comment: I think you might still need to add preventDefault();

Comment: looks great, however, the last `else` seems to be unnecessary

Comment: It's to stop image slider until 3 seconds pass. It is only active while function is going. Just adding it doesn't make a difference

Comment: got you.
nice job!

Comment: And oh, if you want to generelize this code to amount of images, change the `%3` to `%leftImg.length`

Comment: Thanks. I will remember this when I make a slider